# How to prevent file deletion in java using AccessController.doPrivileged

Tags: java, security, permissions

I want to protect a file from deleting in java using FilePermission and AccessController.

I give read permission for file and still can delete a file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilePermission;
import java.security.AccessController;
import java.security.PrivilegedAction;

public class ReadOnlyFile {

  public static void readOnly() throws Exception {
    final File f = new File("/tmp/secure.txt");

    final boolean created = f.createNewFile();
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() + " has been created: " + created);

    final boolean deleted = AccessController.doPrivileged((PrivilegedAction<Boolean>) f::delete, null, new FilePermission(f.getPath(), "read"));
    System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() + " has been deleted: " + deleted);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    readOnly();
  }

}
```

Comment: Note of caution regarding the use of `AccessController`: [JEP 411: Deprecate the Security Manager for Removal](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/411).

Comment: I guess the file will become `readonly` only for other users. The user who is creating the file will always have full access to it.